# Published Blog Post Inherit's Multisite WP Favicon

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

When a child site on my Wordpress Multisite publishes a blog post to Google+ it inherit's the main parent blog's favicon even though a child favicon is present. Is there a special meta tag or just not possible with Google's publishing feature?

Note: child blogs are setup this way

Master Domain: domain.com
Child Blog 1: blog.clientdomain.com
Child Blog 2: blog.clientdomain2.com
etc…

Favicon Meta Tag:

`<link type="image/x-icon" href="http://blog.clientsite.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">`

Update: If the only solution is removing the favicon on the master blog I am open to that being the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on how you have WordPress multisite setup.  The favicon service that Google+ uses only works with favicons located at http://{domain}/favicon.ico.  It doesn't look for the shortcut link you mention above.  So, if you use sub-domains for your sites, then you can have independent favicons for each site, you'll just need to make sure they are able to be accessed from /favicon.ico (or that this URL redirects to where the image actually lives).  If you are using sub-directories for your sites, there is no easy way to fix this right now.